# Ionic 3 File plugin error security err.

Tags: javascript, file, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to read to upload a file read from storage to firebase. 
I am getting this error when reading file as array buffer

```
{"code": 2, message:"SECURITY_ERR"}
```

this is the code

```
 this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(dirPath,url.name).then((buffer)=>{
        // this.upload(buffer,url.name);

        let blob = new Blob([buffer],{type:'image/jpeg'})

        alert(blob);

        firebase.storage().ref('files/'+url.name).put(blob).then((d)=>{
          alert(JSON.stringify(d));
        }).catch(e=>{
          alert(e);
        })
    }).catch(e=>{
      alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    })
```

I have also added all these permissions READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE